# Problema con Array en C

Tags: c, algoritmos, números-primos

tengo este código en c que tendría que devolverme un array con los números primos del 1 al 10, pero tiene un error cuando se intenta crear el array con los numeros primos, no logro ver donde esta el error. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
short int esPrimo(int a);
int * damePrimos(int a); // Va a retornar un array de int.
int main()
{
int * result; // Una variable capaz de recibir un array retornado desde una función
result = damePrimos(10);
for(int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
    printf("%d", result[j]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Personal mente creo que el error se encuentra por aquí, pero no sabría decir con exactitud.

```
int * damePrimos(int a) {
int i;
int c;
for(i = 2; i<a; i++) {

    if(esPrimo(i) == 1) {
      //printf("%d\n", i); //printf(INT) -> INCORRECTO
      c++;
    }

}
int r[c];
for(i = 2; i<a; i++) {
    if(esPrimo(i) == 1) {
        r[i] = i;
    }
}
return r;

}
```

...............

```
short int esPrimo(int a) {
// Voy a querer dividir a "a" por todos los números entre 1 (sin incluirlo) y a/2 incluido
if (a == 1) {
    return 0;
}
int i;
int flag = 1;
for(i=2; i<=a/2; i = i+1) {
    // Para conservar el resto, de dividir sucesivamente a/2, utilizamos el operador módulo %
    // Pero yo necesito saber si alguno de esos restos es DIFERENTE DE CERO. Para esto, vamos a usar 
    un if()
    // Y habrá una variable tipo flag, que será puesta en valor UNO si AL MENOS UNO de los restos fue 
    DIFERENTE DE CERO
    if(a%i == 0) {
        flag = 0;
    }

}

return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no logro ver donde esta el error

El error es que estás usando variables locales:

```
int * damePrimos(int a) {
    int c;
    // ...
    int r[c]; // <<--- variable local
    // ...
    return r;
}
```

Al ser `r` una variable local, su memoria queda libre en el momento en el que la ejecución del programa abandona la función. Esto quiere decir que el programa es libre de reutilizar esa memoria para otros propósitos. Al final, en el puntero que has devuelto solo obtendrás basura, ya que es probable que los valores originales hayan sido sobreeescritos.

Otro problema que tienes es que estás usando VLA (Variable Length Array). En StackOverflow ya se ha contado infinidad de veces lo que es y los problemas que puede causar, no me voy a alargar más con ese tema.

Todo esto se soluciona usando memoria dinámica:

```
int* r = (int*)malloc(c * sizeof(int));

// ...

return r;
```

Por supuesto, una regla de oro al usar memoria dinámica es que toda la memoria que reserves debes liberarla cuando ya no sea necesaria:

```
int main()
{
    int * result = damePrimos(10);
    for(int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
        printf("%d", result[j]);

    free(result); // <<--- Liberamos la memoria
}
```